# Generated CSV cannot be read by Feeds

Tags: 7, views, feeds

Using Views Data Export module, I am generating a CSV file of the latest 10 content. Then on another Drupal site, I am trying to import those nodes with Feeds.

The problem is when I give the url of the generated CSV, Title and Body fields cannot be imported. The nodes are generated, but those two fields are empty. Other fields like tags, date, etc are imported fine.

When I manually download the CSV, put to server via FTP, then make Feeds get the CSV from there, everything works OK.

I also tried the option "Provide as file" from the Views Data Export settings. Not working either.

What is the problem with generated CSV's address?

Comment: Do you know the http response? 404? 500 (server error)..
Permissions, does the second site/server have access to the url. (Just throwing some ideas)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

When I manually open the url, it downloads fine. So I dont think it is a permission issue, etc.

Also some fields are imported fine, some fields are not. But the problem isnt on the file either, because when I put that on the server via FTP, it also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It drove me crazy but in the end, I found the issue.

The website has a default language other than English. When I look at the CSV url (as a logged in user) I see the correct headers in the CSV (because my language is English). But when an anonymous user looks at the url, he sees the translated headers :) So the headers dont match with the ones I set up in the Feeds settings.